# All Greek letters are capitals, no small Greek letters

Tags: insert

So far, I need some Greek letter every now and then. I enter them through:

<kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>8</kbd><kbd>RET</kbd> `GREEK SMALL LETTER LAMBDA` <kbd>RET</kbd> → λ

or simply by

<kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>8</kbd><kbd>RET</kbd> `03bb` <kbd>RET</kbd> →  λ

However, I tried this after a long hiatus, and whatever I do, I obtain the upper case `Λ`. When I try to insert the upper case, I get the upper case too, so the insertions are not just switched.

What's wrong?

Comment: Does 'C-u C-x =' on the resulting character show that it's inserting an upper case lambda? This might just be a font issue.

Comment: The question is missing basic information about the environment. What emacs version do you use on what system? Cannot reproduce the problem with `GNU Emacs 26.1 (build 1, x86_64-unknown-cygwin, GTK+ Version 3.22.28) of 2018-05-28` and also not on `GNU Emacs 26.1 (build 2, x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.18.9) of 2018-05-29`. Note that with some fonts small lambda and capital lambda are difficult to differentiate.

Comment: @rpluim: Yes, I think it's the font. When I copy and paste the letters in another application, I can see the letters in the low case. Anyway, changing the font to DejavuSans solved it.

Answer (score 2):

As per the comments: lower case and upper case lambda were displayed similarly, but changing the font to DejavuSans resolved the issue.